# Angular 5 router.navigate takes me away from the Angular application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

- I have an Angular 4 project that I upgraded to Angular 5 and I noticed that routing appears to be behaving differently, though it could have always been like this.
- My `index.html` file has `<base href="/cool/" />` in the `<head>` element.
- My web-server serves the contents of `index.html` for all requests under `/cool`, for example:

  - `GET /cool`
  - `GET /cool/`
  - `GET /cool/auth`
  - `GET /cool/auth/`
  - `GET /cool/somethingElse/`
  - ...but not for `GET /`

In my `app.routing.ts` file I set these routes up:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home'  , component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'misc'  , component: MiscComponent },
    { path: 'help'  , component: HelpComponent },
    { path: 'auth'  , component: AuthComponent },

    { path: ''      , redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**'    , component: NotFoundComponent }
];
```

Consequently, when a user accesses `http://localhost/cool` the Angular application loads and then pushes a history-state to become `http://localhost/cool/home` (so the address bar changes but the browser doesn't do a full-page-reload of the new location). So far, so good.

There's a log-out button in my page (in HTML controlled by `AppComponent`) that when clicked does this:

```
class AppComponent {

    logOutClicked( event: Event): void {

        this.clientTokenService.clearSavedToken();

        this.router.navigate( ['auth'] );
    }
}
```

...but when this happens the browser does a full page refresh for either `http://localhost` or `http://localhost/auth` (I forget what caused it to do that, I think it was when I did `router.navigate( ['/auth'] )` - I don't have access to the Angular application right now to check).

I'm surprised there isn't an explicit option or function on Angular's router to force it to do an "internal redirect" without causing a full page reload - or is there and I'm just missing something?

Comment: AFAIK angular's router does not cause full page reloads. Maybe you have some piece of code somewhere that sets the window.location property ?

Comment: Also, are there console errors ?

Comment: @YoukouleleY No errors, just the Network tab (and an XHR breakpoint) showing an XHR request for the site root which somehow triggers a whole page reload, it's weird.

Comment: Did you try to enable the router traces with this line : `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})`

Comment: I've seen this happen when you have a button with an onClick handler that routes. If your button is in a form, it may be a submit button without you realizing it, and it's trying to submit the form?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Ah, I have it on an `<a (click)="logoutClicked">` element - I don't think I have an `href=""` on it though.

Answer (score 2):

Use a router link instead of an href. This will route with no reload

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/cool']">Cool Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your "a" tag to a div or a span.
When you have an 'a" tag with no href attribute and no routerLink attribute, it is still a link, with a defualt value which I think is "/".